# unattended-upgrades and postgresql version

Tags: postgresql

Can the `apt dist-upgrade` command On Ubuntu/Debian distros update the version of PostgreSQL?

I've some Ubuntu 18.04 LTS servers using PostgreSQL 9.6 and I don't want that `unattended-upgrades` execution results in a PostgreSQL update.

If I'm not wrong I should have to explicitly install another postgresql version to do so. Otherwise should I blacklist that package update?

Thanks!

Comment: `dist-upgrade` will update everything it can. `unattended-upgrades` will provide security fixes only. If you need to stick with PostgreSQL 9.6, then the unattended upgrades will not touch the DB. That said, you can protect yourself from accidental upgrades to PostgreSQL by commenting out the repository in your `sources.list` file. If you installed the DB from an Ubuntu repository, then you can pin the version so no updates interfere with the database.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want Unattended Upgrades to push security patches while keeping you on 9.6? Or are you saying that you don't want U-U to upgrade you to 9.7? Also, can you be specific about the package names involved? Are those packages from the Ubuntu repositories or from someplace else?

Comment: Thank you all for your help!
At the moment ```unattended-upgrades``` is configured to update only on security channel but I don't know what happens if I enable the "updates" channel. 
To be more specific I don't want U-U to upgrade postgresql to 9.7.
The package involved is ```postgresql-9.6``` from ```http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt``` repository

Comment: Past upgrades have installed the new postgresql, but using the next port (e.g. 5433 instead of 5432), so both may run in parallel.  Dump old db and load new db at your convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unattended Upgrades only works from certain repositories.

Let's take a look at which repositories. Here's the setting in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        // Extended Security Maintenance; doesn't necessarily exist for
        // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
        // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
        // should also install from here by default.
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

Let's interpret that: It means the Unattended Upgrades ONLY looks for security updates in the -security pocket of the Ubuntu repositories. You can change the setting, but the question you asked suggests that you didn't know about it (so it still looks like this).

This is one of the great benefits of using the Ubuntu Repositories: Security updates from the Ubuntu Security Team.

Since you installed Postgresql from someplace else that's not on the Allowed-Origins list (and uses different package names and versions), Unattended Upgrades WON'T apply security updates nor new versions. Nor will the Ubuntu Security Team patch your packages. You are on your own.

- If multiple sources provide the same package **name** (regardless of what the contents are), Unattended Upgrades may indeed install upgrades from sources that are in Allowed-Origins. That might indeed cause problems, so keep your third-party sources to a minimum.
- Generally, most -security pocket upgrades involve patching the currently-available version rather than bumping to a higher version (which can breaks workflows). There are a few exceptions and corner cases.